# Why did this sage plant die?

Tags: herbs

- UK climate, planted in July
- Standard John Innes potting soil
- Not watered, just catches the rain from the balcony, has drainage holes in the bottom of the container
- the balcony is shaded by the trees, so only gets full sun in the late afternoon

Did it just not get enough sun perhaps?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's died back from drought - plants in containers need watering regularly, daily if the weather is very hot, and the UK has had some very hot weather this summer. Even if it rains, not much gets in a container of plants because the foliage keeps most of it out.

That said, Sage (Salvia officinalis) is a woody shrub - it needs a fair amount of space and preferably full sun. The container you used is not ideal for this plant, it would have done better in a bigger pot - but only if you'd kept it watered.

Comment: That does surprise me, I thought it would be too wet! Is it totally dead or could it come back?

Comment: You've said there were drainage holes in the container, which is critically important, of course. Hard to overwater if something can drain freely... there is evidence of a little growth, so its not completely dead. Cut it right back, keep it watered as necessary and see what happens, but it would do better in the ground or  a larger pot.

Answer (score 0):

I think its not a Sage. Looks to me like an Oregano. Both plants are not well suited for your climate and require full sunlight and porous soil with good drainage.